# Multilang sentence to N-gram

Tags: javascript, strings, array, regex

**Task:** Transform sentence to n-gram and remove all punctuation

**Tests:**

> **Input:**  ngram('Name, + other ~ name!', 1)
>
> **Result**: ['Name', 'other', 'name']
>
> **Input:** ngram('Name, + other ~ name!', 2)
>
> **Result:** ['Name other', 'other name']
>
> **Input:** ngram('Name, + other ~ name!', 10)
>
> **Result:** ['Name other name']
>
> **Input:** ngram('Мене також.', 10)
>
> **Result:** ['Мене також']

**Code:**

```
function ngram(data, order) {
    const regex = /[^A-Za-zА-ЯЄІЇа-яєії0-9_']/g
    let ngramsArray = []

    data = data
      .replace(regex, ' ')
      .split(' ')
      .filter(element => element.length > 0)

    if (order > data.length) {
      order = data.length
    }

    for (let i = 0; i < data.length - (order - 1); i++) {
      let subNgramsArray = []

      for (let j = 0; j < order; j++) {
        subNgramsArray.push(data[i + j])
      }

      ngramsArray = [...ngramsArray, subNgramsArray.join(' ')]
    }

    return ngramsArray
  }
```